# SQL conditional: using Regex formatter for "Like"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net, vb6

I have a record in a database like this:  1K-05, in a column called "DocXmtlNum"

The SQL statement to try to get it is like this:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT DocXmtlNum FROM table1 WHERE DocXmtlNum Like '#?[A-Z]*' ORDER BY DocXmtlNum Desc"
```

However, it does not grab any records.  I am assuming that the "#?[A-Z]*" part is saying that it wants to get records that start with a number, is followed by a letters, and is followed by any other characters.  What's wrong with this?  How would I write the regular expression to get a record that is a number followed by a letter, and followed by any character?

Note: The SQL statement was auto translated from VB6 to vb.net4, so there were errors introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
WHERE DocXmtlNum REGEXP '^[0-9]?[A-Z]-.+$'
```

This checks for:

- An optional digit
- A letter
- A hyphen
- At least one more character

Comment: ok thanks!  what does the ? mean?  In the original statement in vb6, what does the # mean?

Comment: I don't know what the vb6 pattern means.  The `?` means one or most of the preceding elements (in this case a digit).  I might guess that in the original code, the `#` was for a number.